# Spring boot NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a Spring boot application without a main class.Here's what I have done so far.

```
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

            @Override
            public SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
                return builder.sources(Application.class);
            }
    }
```

My controller class looks something like this

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(path="/api",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String insertData(@RequestBody String rawJsonData,HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException, IOException{
        JSONParser jparser=new JSONParser();
        Object jsonObj=jparser.parse(rawJsonData);
        JSONObject jObject=(JSONObject)jsonObj;

        FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Aayushi.txt"));
        filewriter.write(jObject.toJSONString());
        return rawJsonData;

    }
}
```

And pom.xml has the following dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>API</groupId>
  <artifactId>API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
             <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
         </configuration>
         </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency><!-- Add tomcat only if I want to run directly -->

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>Application</start-class>
         <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

But when I run the above code using mvn spring-boot:run then it gives me the following error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building API 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ API >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ API ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ API ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ API ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ API ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ API <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ API ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:502)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.456 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-16T02:50:22+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/177M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project API: An exception occurred while running. javax/servlet/ServletContext: javax.servlet.ServletContext -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong in this. Also, my code is not able to process HttpServletRequest as a Http request.Not sure why it is happening.

Comment: You are missing a dependency  for Server Api in your maven build path

Comment: It's also giving me an error as 'No compiler found'.I tried configuring the build path but error is not getting resolved after that too!What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try adding below. Le us know if it helps!

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also add main() method to your Application class...without it i think your spring application won't run.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
```

Comment: Small thing. Web server application runs on may have bundled servlet api. It is better to add `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: even after adding the dependency,I am getting these errors     
[WARNING] 
java.lang.Exception: The specified mainClass doesn't contain a main method with appropriate signature.
 at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:509)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Application.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
 at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:502)
 ... 1 more      and the build is failing @SanketD

Comment: you have to add main method also.

Comment: Where did you get `3.0.1` version? Is it even out?